# Oracle "ORA-01008" Error. Variable Not Bound

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have just started with `PL/SQL` and writing a simple fundamental code. I am not getting, what is wrong with the code.

```
DECLARE
role_test varchar(40) := 'Programmer';
BEGIN
update veer_test set project_id=1008420 where role=:role_test;
END;
```

I am getting `ORA-01008: not all variables bound`.

Earlier I tried:

```
DECLARE
role varchar(40) := 'Programmer';
BEGIN
update veer_test set project_id=1008420 where role=role;
END;
```

This updated all the rows of the table. Well this was justifiable. But what if I want to use the same variable name as in the table. I also tried:

```
role=:role;
```

But same error `ORA-01008`

Comment: where role=role; is making no difference between the table's field role and the variable named role. Do not use the same name for field and variable. Besides, you don't have to use : to reference the variable, just use for example:
where role=v_role;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE
role_test varchar(40) := 'Programmer';
BEGIN
update veer_test set project_id=1008420 where role=role_test;
END;
```

Comment: But why can't I use the same variable name as I have in my table? say `role`. And then what is the difference between `:role_test` and `role_test`.?

Comment: @Veer It's not a dynamic SQL. For more details: [SO: Use of bind variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209981/use-of-bind-variable)

Comment: @Veer If you use `role=role` with the same name as a field in the table you just compare field with its self not with a variable so it is always true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same variable name as your column name, You can try with a procedure like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE role_p(role VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
     UPDATE veer_test SET project_id=1008422 WHERE role = role_p.role;
END;
```

To Execute:

```
EXECUTE role_p('Programmer');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consult `v$reserved_words` in order to determine if you can use a specific word such as `ROLE` in PL/SQL:

```
select res_attr from v$reserved_words where keyword = 'ROLE';
```

The fact that this statement returns a row indicates that indeed `ROLE` is indeed a keyword, and hence cannot be used in PL/SQL. Yet, `res_attr_` is `N` which indicates that the word can be used in a table for an attribute name.

See also [v$reserved_words on tahiti.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2134.htm#REFRN30204)

Answer (score 0):

you try

```
DECLARE
role_test varchar(40) := 'Programmer';
BEGIN
update veer_test set project_id=1008420 where role=role_test;
END;
```

May this work

Comment: But why can't I use the same variable name as I have in my table? say `role`. And then what is the difference between `:role_test` and `role_test`?